# Packets arrive, but listening app doesn't get them?

Tags: iptables

We receive requests routed by our firewall, the packets have the correct IP and port but are not received by our application.

Here is the log from iptables :

```
Sep 18 15:53:42 frtrans01 kernel:  INPUT TCP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:13:2a:dc:58:49:3b:00:5c:11:08:00 SRC=109.1.186.112 DST=x.x.x.x LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=117 ID=1616 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3766 DPT=6322 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

A packet which is read ok is like :

```
Oct  6 15:41:50 frtrans01 kernel: INPUT TCP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:13:2a:dc:58:49:3b:00:5c:11:08:00 SRC=170.118.98.33 DST=x.x.x.x LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=45368 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41638 DPT=6322 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

And the lsof result of the app listening :

```
[root@frtrans01 ~]# lsof |grep LISTEN
...
java       2301      root   63u     IPv6    3556600                 TCP *:emp-server2 (LISTEN)
```

The port emp-server2 is the port 6322.

What is wrong with the packet received ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks kind of like your daemon is listening only with IPv6, but your packets are coming in with IPv4. That could be a problem.

Is that right? Or am I overlooking something? If I'm wrong, then use wireshark or tcpdump to see if the packets are actually arriving.